# Need help solving a logarithmic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

I got the following equation to solve for $x$:

$\log_3{(x-3)}= \frac{1}{ 2  \log_2{3} } + \log_{81}(3x-13)^2$

No idea if this is needed but I first tried to bring them to the same base:

$\frac{\log(x-3)}{\log 3} = \frac{\log 2}{2 \log 3} + \frac{\log ((3x-13)^2)}{\log 81}$

Anyone an idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying the both sides of
$$\frac{\log(x-3)}{\log 3} = \frac{\log 2}{2 \log 3} + \frac{\log ((3x-13)^2)}{\log 81}$$
by $4\log 3\ (=\log 81)$ gives
$$4\log (x-3)=2\log 2+\log ((3x-13)^2)$$
So,
$$(x-3)^4=2^2(3x-13)^2$$
Use here that
$$A^2=B^2\iff (A+B)(A-B)=0$$
with $x-3\gt 0$ and $3x-13\not=0$.